# Display an arrayList of arrayLists in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

I have an arraylist and each element of the arrayList contains a small arrayList of data.

I need to create a table from this data. What would you recommend being the best route to take with solving this?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Do you want to display a textual table or a GUI table?

Comment: What does the inner list contain? Does it contain objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a GUI table of a List of lists, I would create a class that implements the 'TableModel' interface, and has a constructor that takes in your 'List>'

```
public class ListTableModel <T> implements TableModel {

    private List<List<T>> source;

    public ListTableModel(List<List<T>> source) {

        this.source = source;

    }


    //Override 'getRowCount' 
    //The row count would be calculated as the size of the outer list.
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return source.size();
    }

    //Override 'getColumnCount'
    //The column count would be calculated as the max size of the inner lists
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        int max = 0;
        for(List<T> row : source) {
            max = Math.max(max, row.size());
        }
        return max;
    }

    //Override 'getColumnName'
    //Lets go ahead and just give a unique name to each column based on the index.
    //This could be populated from an input taken by the constructor, but we
    //won't worry about that now.
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return "Column " + columnIndex;
    }

    //Override 'getColumnClass'
    //The class would technically be the generic type 'T', so to get this we 
    //will simply just get the calss of the first element.
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return source.get(0).get(0).getClass();
    }


    //Override 'isCellEditable'
    //I'm going to assume we don't want cell to be editable.
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        List<T> row = source.get(rowIndex);
        if(columnIndex >= row.size())
            return null;
        else 
            return row.get(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //required but we will assume that you cannot change the source list
        //if we needed to, it wouldn't be too difficult to implement.
    }

    @Override
    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
        //required but not used (will only be used if the source could change)
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
        //required but not used (will only be used if the source could change)
    }

}
```

you would use this model with your list like so:

```
List<List<String>> myList = new ArrayList();

//Populate 'myList'...

JTable table = new JTable();

//Add table to view...

table.setModel(new ListTableModel(myList));
```

EDIT I can show you how to implement TableModel if you would like.

Comment: That would be great if you could give us a quick tutorial on how to implement TableModel! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much, i'll give it a go. I Really aprreciate the help

Comment: @user2029412 I changed the code to implement TableModel. This is a very basic implementation and I would recommend looking at Che's example of creating a Table Model. By the way, the great thing about creating a class like this, is that you can reuse it in any of your projects!

Answer (score 3):

See [How to create a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

A small example showing how to create a Model and store your objects in the model. Any operation on the data should be done using the model.

Create a model and use a list to store the data for that table. As shown in the below example. Each of the row in the table is a `Student` object and each object is stored in the list. Traverse the list and get each object and show in the table. This is done using `getValueAt(..)` method.

[image: JTable Model Example]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class JTableList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CustomModel model = new CustomModel();
                JTable table = new JTable();
                table.setModel(model);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);             
            }
        };

        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }

}

class CustomModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    List<Student> data;
    String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Age"};

    public CustomModel() {
        data = new ArrayList<Student>();

        data.add(new Student("Amar", 1));
        data.add(new Student("Sam", 2));
        data.add(new Student("Amar", 1));
        data.add(new Student("Sam", 2));
        data.add(new Student("Amar", 1));
        data.add(new Student("Sam", 2));


    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Student student = data.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return student.getName();
        case 1:
            return student.getAge();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

}

class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Student(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [List Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/list-table-model/) can be used to do this.

It is a more complex and flexible solution implementing the earlier suggestions given in this thread.